# Unexpected Blank Window Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

A blank window along with the main window is created.

I've seen other questions but my case is different I'm not using any constructor.
The blank window appears when I initialize `ttk.style`.

```
correct_style = ttk.Style()
correct_style.configure('correct.TButton',background='#39b54a')
root = ThemedTk(theme="equilux")
```

If I delete these lines, the empty window doesn't appear.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. How and when you're creating the root window is an important detail that you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you call the two lines before creating the instance of `Tk()`, something like below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

correct_style = ttk.Style()
correct_style.configure('correct.TButton',background='#39b54a')

root = tk.Tk()
...
root.mainloop()
```

As `ttk.Style()` requires an instance of `Tk()`, if there is none, it will be created implicitly for you.  So there will be two instances of `Tk()`.

Move the two lines after creating `Tk()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

correct_style = ttk.Style()
correct_style.configure('correct.TButton',background='#39b54a')

...
root.mainloop()
```